# Ajax request loads entire page in div when it's not supposed to

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am trying to do something very simple, a user clicks a link and a mini-form with a file upload input appears somewhere below it.

However, my ajax code is not cooperating. Instead, it loads the entire current (i think) page. I had this issue again some time ago and i managed to fix it, however for the life of me i can't remember how i did it.

Now the really strange thing is that when i try it on my local computer it works fine, but on the actual web server it doesn't.

Code:

```
function ajaxRequest(targetUri, parameters, cbFunction){

if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }else{
    request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }


  request.onreadystatechange = cbFunction;
  request.open("POST", targetUri, true);
  request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  request.send(parameters);

   }

function addImage(){
  parameters = "action=ajaxRequest";
  ajaxRequest("http://www.mysite.com/gallery/addImage.php", parameters, function(){
    if((request.readyState == 4) && (request.status == 200)){
   document.getElementById("formContainer").innerHTML = request.responseText;
    }
  });
```

}

And my PHP file:

```
function addImage(){
  echo '
 <div class="mainBlockBody">
   <form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="hidden" name="galleryAction" value="addImage" />
  <input type="file" name="upFile" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
   </form>
 </div>
  ';
}

if($_POST['action'] == 'ajaxRequest'){
  addImage();
}
```

Link & placeholder:

```
<a href="javascript:addImage()">Add Image</a>
<div id="formContainer"></div>
```

Any help is much appreciated!

EDIT:

I think i have narrowed down the problem to the... path. In this page http://bit.ly/dXrGY6 it all works fine, using a relative path. Replacing it with an absolute path like "http://www..." or "../test/....." makes it malfunction again. I am using absolute paths in another section of my site and it works fine: http://bit.ly/fCmmjy . I dont know why it doesn't work here...

I can't figure out what is wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

are you sure your php code is not spitting out anymore html?
try adding a `die`

```
if($_POST['action'] == 'ajaxRequest'){
  addImage();
  die();
}
```

Comment: I tried this by using exit() before and it didn't work. I tried it again just in case with die(), it didn't work either. Maybe it is something relevant with the page structure and not the code itself? Here is more or less the same code on another page (you can view source), working properly http://bit.ly/fCmmjy (click on the flags to change the translation). And here is the page with the current issue (you have to be logged in - sorry) http://bit.ly/ijIyc2